# $pull is not working in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run a function which deletes label which associated with any items.So here $pull is not working.

The "item" schema

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
  item_title: {type: String, required: true},
  discription:{type: String},
  label : {type:Array ,label_id : String },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  _list: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'List'}
});
```

in controller

```
exports.deleteLabel = function (req, res){

    var label = new Label({_id:req.params.label_id});
   // label.remove();
    Item.find({},function(error,items){
        items.forEach(function(item){
            //console.log("dada");

            Item.findByIdAndUpdate(item._id,
            { $pull: {"label" : { label_id :req.params.label_id }} }
            ,function(error,result){
                if(result)console.log(result);
                else console.log("not removed");
              });
        })
  })
}
```

i cant understand what is the problem. Please help me out of this.
I googled about this problem, but I have not found yet.
So please suggest **ANY** method that can solve my problem.I just want to delete a label from an array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you instead try

```
exports.deleteLabel = function (req, res){

    var label = new Label({_id:req.params.label_id});
   // label.remove();
    Item.find({},function(error,items){
        items.forEach(function(item){
            //console.log("dada");

            Item.findByIdAndUpdate(item._id,
            { $pull: {"label.label_id" :req.params.label_id } }
            ,function(error,result){
                if(result)console.log(result);
                else console.log("not removed");
              });
        })
  })
}
```

Comment: No it's not working.Can you suggest any other method?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution....
Just few changes in schema and its done!!!!

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
      item_title: {type: String, required: true},
      discription:{type: String},
      label : [label_id : String] , //Changes made here
      created_at: Date,
      updated_at: Date,
      _list: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'List'}
    });
```